# Aplicacion web y app movil en phonegab utilizando socket io

Tags: javascript, nodejs, socket.io

mi duda como puedo relacionar estas dos plataformas que quiero hacer ya que por un lado se esta desarrollando un chat con phonegab y por el otro una aplicacion web en donde llegaran los mensajes ...que debo considerar ya que pues los tengo en directorios separados

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a Stack Overflow. Las preguntas sin código no son bien recibidas por la comunidad. Pásate por [esta sección](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que aprendas como realizar una pregunta y evitar que te la cierren.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes relacionarles creando una api donde se va a comunicar tanto la aplicación web como la aplicación móvil y en esta api se pueden conectar los dos por medio de sockets para el chat